# Plotting bar charts side by side

Tags: python, bar-chart, visualization

Can I plot these two side bar charts side by side

```
import pandas as pd

a=[('Female','0'),
('Female','0'),
('Female','0'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Female','1'),
('Male','0'),
('Male','0'),
('Male','0'),
('Male','0'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1'),
('Male','1')]

df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['Gender','Placement_B'])

gender=pd.crosstab(df['Gender'], df['Placement_B'])

g_norm=pd.crosstab(df['Gender'], df['Placement_B'],margins=True, normalize='index')

gender.plot.bar(stacked=True)

g_norm.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Comment: Use subplots if you like matplotlib.  Also, do you think we're able to get what you're plotting by this question?? Atleast put some reproducible data.

Comment: Apologies Vicrobot. I have updated with data. I am not able to plot using crosstab with matplotlib. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that you had problems with plotting the crosstab data. Here is a way to plot it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['Gender','Placement_B'])
gender=pd.crosstab(df['Gender'], df['Placement_B'])
g_norm=pd.crosstab(df['Gender'], df['Placement_B'],margins=True, normalize='index')

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.bar(gender.index.values, gender.iloc[:, 1])
ax1.bar(gender.index.values, gender.iloc[:, 0])
ax2.bar(g_norm.index.values, g_norm.iloc[:, 1])
ax2.bar(g_norm.index.values, g_norm.iloc[:, 0])

# Probably the way that is more relevant for this case

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
gender.iloc[:].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax1)
g_norm.iloc[:].plot.bar(stacked=True, ax=ax2)
```

Comment: If you want to plot bars side to side check this: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-barchart-py

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, his does not stack my 1s and 0s. It gives me a sum instead of count. I need counts and that is why I'm using a crosstab.

Comment: Alternative way is to use for example: ax1 = gender.iloc[:].plot.bar(stacked=True) 
And same for g_norm data. This way you will see the actual sum also as stacked. :)

Comment: Can we use the same method (ax=ax1) to plot pie charts as well? It seems to be not working for me

Comment: Seems to be working a bit oddly for me. Anyway, if it seems to be working why not to use it. How did you modify the code exactly? :)

Answer (score 0):

This question does not specify what package you are using. If you use [DataMelt program](https://jwork.org/dmelt), you can plot bar charts or histograms side by side by using HPlot canvas, and navigate usibf cd() method. Here are [several DataMelt example that show histograms](https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?art=Histograms/1D) side by side. If you do not like the histogram presentation, use HChart class as [shown here](https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?keyword=HChart)

Comment: I have used only pandas. I am also open to an option where I can plot value counts using matplotlib so that I can use matplotlib.figure.